# Does not work credentials in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have created credentials `(method: username and password)` in Jenkins with name `wwe_hello`.
For test, i created pipeline with name `test`:

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'slave1'}
    environment {
        CREDS = credentials("wwe_hello")
    }      
    stages {
        stage('WWE') {

            steps {
                sh 'echo "$CREDS"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In result i have:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on slave1 in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: wwe_hello
Finished: FAILURE
```

Where, i have error. I am doing everything according to working examples and documentation. But i don't understand, why it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the pipeline step documentation for withCredentials.  You don't need to create the environment variable with env - withCredentials does it for you:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('only') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([
                    usernamePassword(
                        credentialsId: 'CRED', 
                        usernameVariable: 'USER', 
                        passwordVariable: 'PASS'
                        )]) {
                    sh '''
                        echo "The username is: ${USER}"
                        echo "The password is : ${PASS}"
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create credentials with name "wwe_hello"

1. [Go to credentials Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STsR2.png)
2. [Under stores scoped to jenkins, select jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOvcY.png)
3. [Select global credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap09x.png)
4. [Select add credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPsVY.png)
5. [give credentails (see in the dropdown, secret text has been selected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uizvZ.png)